# Jquery Autocomplete + ASP.NET MVC 3 not displaying the results

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

My View Code:

Script and Css:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Input text:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Filter.HouseName, new { style = "width: 205px", onKeyUp = "updateHouseNames()" })
```

Javascript:

```
function updateHouseNames() {
    var houseArray = new Array();

    $.post('@Url.Action("LoadHouses")', { houseName: $("#Filter_HouseName").val() }, function(houses) {
        houseArray = houses;
    });

    $("#Filter_HouseName").autocomplete({
        source: houseArray 
    });
}
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadHouses(string houseName)
{
    var houses = this.HouseService.SelectByName(houseName).Select(e => new String(e.Name.ToCharArray())).ToArray();

    return Json(houses);
}
```

I debug the javascript and the houses are selected.. but the results are not displayed in autocomplete. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think you should be doing it this way. If you need to customize the logic then use a callback on the `autocomplete` method:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Filter_HouseName').autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            var houseArray = new Array();

            $.post('@Url.Action("LoadHouses")', { houseName: term }, function(houses) {
                houseArray = houses;
                response(houseArray);
            });                
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why the way i did doesn't work? I used this exemple: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: You used which example? There are many examples on that one page.

Comment: The first one. "Default Functionality".

Comment: They are using a static array that does not change in that example. They are also only wiring up the autocomplete event once. You are doing it multiple times which is probably not good.